# How can I get data from the view with Doctrine and createQueryBuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need do a sql query for a view in the databse for get data I use the follow code:

```
$qb= $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        return $qb->select('count(c)')
                ->from('AppsBundle:Apps_View', 'c')
                ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

This query fails:

1. I have not an Entity for `Apps_Views`, `s`
2. The entities were generated with the console.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an entity that reflects your view. You just have to treat your view like a regular table, and query it like a regular table:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="your_view")
 */
class YourView {
    // ...
}
```

Beware that if you run the command doctrine:schema:update --force ORM will try to create a new table from this view Entity. You should use Doctrine Migration tools anyway.